# Is there a reason why I shouldn't set a size of blob to maximum size of 8TB?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am connected to Azure blob storage and we need to upload files bigger than **256MB**.

I followed documentation and created PageBlob and than uploaded files through PutPage.

The problem is that I don't know in advance how big the data is going to be so I set it to the max size of **8TB**. 
Is there a reason why I shouldn't do this?

As far as I know, the max size is only the maximum possible size for the blob and shouldn't cause any issues with memory.

Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you mean to use Page Blobs? Those are usually for VM disks https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-pageblob-overview

Comment: Well, I don't know if we have a choice, but thanks for the doc. I'm sure it will help

Comment: What kind of content are you trying to upload?

Comment: Well it make no sense to allows a file bigger than the available space you are willing to have or the bandwidth you want to pay. You can prevent abuse where one would try to upload very large file either by error or purposely to fill your storage.

Comment: It's customer data, we upload table content to our storages.

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience and according to the REST API reference [`Put Page`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-page), the API requires to set the value of the header parameter `Content-Length` with a specific number of bytes  being transmitted in the request body, not an approximate value or possible value, as the figure below.

[image]

Otherwise, Azure Storage will refuse the request and response an error after it checked the validity of the request on cloud. I think it's the real reason about the errors you might get from [`Common REST API Error Codes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/common-rest-api-error-codes) and [`Blob Service Error Codes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-error-codes).